# How to build vertical navigation with horizontal sub menu in one line?

Tags: jquery, html, css, navbar

I have to build a vertical navigation. It's a bit special because the sub navigation **should be displayed right next to the main links in the same row by clicking the main links** like this:

```
 Item 1 
 Item 2   Subitem 1 | Subitem 2 
 Item 3
 Item 4   Subitem 1 | Subitem 2 
 Item 5
```

It works as expected, but if main links have a sub, main links will be displayed after the sub menu instead of displaying it before. I thougt it makes sense to use `float:left;` for the `.sub-menu` to get both on the same row. But with this it looks like:

```
 Item 1 
 Subitem 1 | Subitem 2    Item 2
 Item 3
 Subitem 1 | Subitem 2    Item 4
 Item 5
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u4zpdpg7/). Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to float the `li` elements in the top level menu `left`, as well as those in `.sub-menu`:

```css
ul > li > a {
    float: left;
    clear: both;
}
.sub-menu {
    display: none;
    float: left;
}
.sub-menu li {
    float: left;
}
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/u4zpdpg7/3/)

Comment: The `toggle()` prevents that the links in the submenu are clickable, see my updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u4zpdpg7/6/) - added links to google for the first submenu. Do you have any ideas why this happens?